# Listen to double key press using Chrome Commands API

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to listen for a double key press using the Chrome Commands API.

For example, I want to open a search window when the user double taps the shift key.

I have tried this;

```
"commands": {
    "_execute_page_action": {
        "suggested_key": {
            "default": "Shift+Shift"
        },
        "description": "..."
    }
}
```

But attempting to load the extension returns the following;

```
Failed to load extension from: /example_path
Invalid value for 'commands[1].default': Shift+Shift.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs:

> Supported keys: <kbd>A</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd>, <kbd>0</kbd>-<kbd>9</kbd>, <kbd>,</kbd>, <kbd>.</kbd>, <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>End</kbd>, <kbd>PageUp</kbd>, <kbd>PageDown</kbd>, <kbd>Space</kbd>, <kbd>Insert</kbd>, <kbd>Delete</kbd>, Arrow keys (<kbd>Up</kbd>, <kbd>Down</kbd>, <kbd>Left</kbd>, <kbd>Right</kbd>) and the <kbd>Media</kbd> Keys (<kbd>MediaNextTrack</kbd>, <kbd>MediaPlayPause</kbd>, <kbd>MediaPrevTrack</kbd>, <kbd>MediaStop</kbd>).
>
> Note: All key combinations must include either <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>* or <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

You can read more about commands API [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands).

Comment: Could you add a more significant portion in your quote? Specifically, the previous paragraph. I don't want to intrude and edit it in myself.